# How to Re-change the SHELL to default bash instead of zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

1. Initially had bash as default shell prompt and the ~ had .bashrc, .bash_profile etc file.
2. To try zsh, I installed the zsh locally and also have the .zshrc in the ~ path.
3. Then to have the default shell as zsh, I tried chsh -s ~/local path/zsh pointing to my local zsh. After entering the password, it got changed and was able to run and test things.
4. Now, when I tried going back to default shell of bash, using the same command in step 3, it says the shell got changed. Then I closed the terminal and re-opened and it keep showing the zsh as default with that usual zshell configuration prompt.
5. I tried removing all the .zshrc etc etc. and reopened the terminal again, but its not changing. Also tried killing the vnc session and re-opened a new one and the result is same.

I am confused what am I supposed to do now to get back to the default bash shell. Please let me know. Thanks.

1. Used the following command: chsh -s /bin/bash
   It asked for default password, after entering it says Shell Changed.
2. When I try grep bash /etc/shells it shows,
   /bin/bash
   /usr/bin/bash
3. I closed the terminal and re-opened and
   it stays to the same default zsh and ask to configure the zshell prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
chsh -s $(which bash) {{user}}
```

Change `{{user}}` to your user login.

or use `systemd-homed`[[1]](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-homed.service.html):

```
homectl update --shell=$(which bash) {{user}}
```

Sources:

- https://man.archlinux.org/man/chsh.1
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chsh
- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-chsh-command
- https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-csh-command/

Comment: Its work machine and not personal one. So, dont have the sudo permission. Even when tried with user it says,

Changing shell for <user name>
chsh: Shell not changed.

Comment: In this case, i really don't know how to proceed, maybe without `sudo`?

Comment: Sudo doesn't need for `chsh`: `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 34864 авг 16 17:10 /usr/bin/chsh`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change **default shell** use `chsh -s "$(which bash)` under the your account.

After this you must to relogin.

Bash doesn't read .zshrc, and even if you'll remove this, nothing happened.
To understand, what is the shell you are using, try this command:

```
➭ ps -p $$
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  14321 pts/4    00:01:01 zsh
```

Or show `$SHELL` variable content:

```
➭ echo ${SHELL}
/usr/bin/zsh
```

If you use Bash and your prompt doesn't look "normally", you just can change this in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` files.

Comment: 1. If i try echo ${SHELL} it says /bin/bash
2. But if I try ps -p $$, it says : 65822 pts/8    00:00:00 zsh

So confused, how to get back to normal bash.

Comment: 1. I tried chsh -s "$(which bash)" and still the same. It says shell changed, but eventually it stays with zsh..

Comment: What is saying `ps -up $$`?

Comment: Of course, you must relogin after `chsh`, because `chsh` just replace shell path in the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: When you say relogin meaning ? I connect to my machine via vnc.. I tried killing my vnc and re-created one and entered and the behavior is still the same.

Comment: ps -up $$ shows,
user_name   75330  0.2  0.0 136248  3172 pts/8    Ss   12:14   0:00 /home/username

Comment: You must to end session (console or GUI), as you did this, when changing shell before.

Comment: When you've done `chsh -s ~/local path/zsh`, record in the `/etc/passwd` file was changed (see `man chsh`). On the next login (not VNC session finishing, but real system login), system read this record and run `~/local path/zsh` when you run terminal app, for example. If you don't relogin, system don't reread configuration and continue to use precious shell.

Comment: If you use `tmux` or `screen` in console, and make `detach`, you **don't relogin**, if you use VNC server, after VNC session end, system usually doesn't end user session in the you GUI.

Comment: Is it possible use `Log out` menu item or button in the your desktop manager or desktop environment under the VNC session?